# statically link with OpenSSL library

Tags: c, windows, linker, openssl, mingw

I am using OpenSSL-Win32 library on an x86_64 win7 machine, with MinGW gcc compiler. I am linking the `libeay32.a` and `ssleay32.a` statically to my program. No warning or error code is generated.

However, after the compiling and linking, the executable file exit with

```
The application was unable to start correctly, 0xc0000013
```

I checked my destination executable with dependency walker and it shows

```
C:\windows\system32\libeay32.lib
```

is linked to my program! Then I renamed that file to something like `~libeay32.lib` and, **without** recompile my program and reopen it with dependency walker, now

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyqt4\LIBEAY32.DLL
```

is linked to the program. Clearly static library `libeay32.a` is not working and my program is dynamically searching for the library.

Comment: Maybe libeay32.a just a stub library that loads a dynamic library at run time?

Comment: @willus Hi, I copied libeay32.lib from openssl's lib folder to my program's folder and the compiled program could work properly. However the libeay32.a has 2M+ bytes of content and libeay32.lib has 1.6M bytes so I think libeay32.a should have the right functioning code in it. But I am still not able to link it into my program.